# Open a particular tab in tab bar after push notification

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications, uitabbarcontroller

I need to push to a particular tab bar view controller after I receive a push notification. When I try to push it doesn't show tab bar below.

Please check the following code:-

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc: TabBarViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarViewController") as! TabBarViewController
            vc.selectedIndex = 3
            self.window?.rootViewController  = vc
```

Example,

```
A -> tabbar -> B -> B1
        -> c
        -> D
```

I need to open B1 directly from push notification

Comment: Please show the part of your code that handles incoming notifications

Comment: @ØyvindHauge I am able to push to a specific tab bar controller. But I need to open another view controllers which comes after clicking on a button in specific tab bar.

Comment: I have updated my question, please check

Comment: I have no idea of what you are trying to achieve. Sorry.